# GetObject() not working after runtime update from Nodejs6.1 to Nodejs8.1

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, fs, aws-sdk-js

I am using `AWS Lambda` with NodeJS runtime and I recently received a notification from `AWS` telling that they will stop maintaining `lambdas` running on `node.js 6.10` runtime.

Basically, I am trying to get objects from `S3` and create a stream from these objects in order to extract the data from a `xlsx` file.

This is the code I am trying to execute inside my lambda. This chunk of code worked on the `node.js 6.10` runtime but does not work on the `node.js 8.10` runtime.

```
function getWorkbookFromS3(s3Params): Promise<XLSX.WorkBook> {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        const buffers = [];
        S3Service.getObject(s3Params).createReadStream()
        .on('error', (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }).on('data', (chunk) => {
            buffers.push(chunk);
        }).on('end', () => {
            const buffer = Buffer.concat(buffers);
            const workbook = XLSX.read(buffer, { type: 'buffer', cellDates: true });
            resolve(workbook);
        })
    });
}
```

Any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: please provide an error output

Comment: The thing is that there is no error output...

Comment: Are you sure that version of xlsx that your are using supports Node.js 8.10?

Comment: Not for 100% but the thing is that the event listeners on `createReadStream()` are not even called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to the use of this function inside a `lambda`. I did not get any error, neither any result because once the `lambda` stopped its execution, the code inside the function `getWorkbookFromS3(s3Params)` could not get executed since it is a promise.

The way I called this function before was like this:

```
getWorkbookFromS3(s3Params).then((d) => {
    // do someting
});
```

But it didn't work. As a result, I had to add an `await` keyword in order to force the `promise` to be executed and prevent the `lambda` to stop its execution.

```
await getWorkbookFromS3(s3Params).then((d) => {
    // do someting
});
```